# Spring-Hateoas Client using Traverson

Tags: client, resttemplate, spring-hateoas, hal-json

I want to consume my rest-service by Spring-Hateoas by Traverson, but I come to the following issue I didn't find anything in web.
I am using **Spring-Boot 1.1.10.RELEASE**.

My Client Call looks like follows:

```
... 

final Traverson traverson = new Traverson(new URI("http://localhost:8080/bbsng-app-rest"), MediaTypes.HAL_JSON);

...
```

And I get following Issue:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.hateoas.client.Traverson
at at.compax.bbsng.client.mvc.client.service.BerufServiceImpl.findeAlleBerufe(BerufServiceImpl.java:41)
at at.compax.bbsng.client.mvc.rest.controller.BerufController$1.call(BerufController.java:25)
at at.compax.bbsng.client.mvc.rest.controller.BerufController$1.call(BerufController.java:1)
at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager$4.run(WebAsyncManager.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

=====

**Relevant Configurations:**

**POM:**

```
...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

...
```

**Application-Class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HAL)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationClientMvc {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationClientMvc.class, args);
    }

    ...
```

====

**Rest-Application Response when calling above mentioned URL:**

```
{
   "link": null,
   "_links":
   {
       "self":
       {
           "href": "http://localhost:8080/bbsng-app-rest"
       },
       "berufe":
       {
           "href": "http://localhost:8080/bbsng-app-rest/beruf"
       },
       "betriebe":
       {
           "href": "http://localhost:8080/bbsng-app-rest/betrieb"
       },
       "fachrichtungen":
       {
           "href": "http://localhost:8080/bbsng-app-rest/fachrichtung"
       }
   }
}
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, it seems Spring-Hateoas needs additional dependency Json-Path.

So following dependency will be expected:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Just stumbled on this answer. If this solves the problem, feel free to accept your own answer, which is perfectly ok.